# Well-definedness of total derived functor, and induced map on homotopy categories

Tags: category-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $A$ be an abelian category with enough injectives, let $K(A)$ denote the homotopy category (objects = chain complexes, morphisms = chain maps mod chain homotopies), and let $D(A)$ be the derived category (localization of $K(A)$ at the quasi-isomorphisms).  Then if $F$ is a left-exact functor $A \to A'$,  we speak of the total derived functor $RF: D(A) \to D(A')$ which proceeds by starting with a chain complex, resolving it with an injective complex, and then applying $F$.

1. Is this total derived functor only really well-defined up to natural isomorphism?  After all, it seems to depend on the choice of injective resolution (though different injective resolutions yield quasi-isomorphic images).
2. It seems to me we could equally well have made this construction on the level of the homotopy category, i.e. make a total derived functor $RF: K(A) \to K(A')$.  Why do we pass to the derived category in this construction, where we seemingly lose some information?

Comment: Derived functors have a universal property, so they are as well-defined as any other construction defined by universal properties. However, this universal property is only at the level of derived categories, not homotopy categories. Perhaps [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4371278/5191) is helpful.