# Definition of Tor functor in an arbitrary abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, tensor-products, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category. We define $\text{Ext}_\mathcal{C}^n(A,B)$ for objects $A$ and $B$ via $n$-extensions of $A$ by $B$ as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Construction_of_Ext_in_abelian_categories), with $\text{Ext}_{\mathcal{C}}^0(A,B):=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B).$ This coincides with the definition of $\text{Ext}$ in terms of resolutions if $\mathcal{C}$ has enough projectives or enough injectives.

Is there a corresponding definition for $\text{Tor}_\mathcal{C}^n(A,B)$? $\text{Ext}$ starts with the abelian group of morphisms $A\to B$, whereas Tor starts with the tensor product $A\otimes B$. Yet there is no tensor product in an arbitrary abelian category, so I don't see how Tor can work in this abstract setting. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't miss anything. It is not possible to define $\mathrm{Tor}^n$ in an arbitrary abelian category. You need an abelian $\otimes$-category with enough projectives.

Comment: @downvoter: please explain what I can improve.

Comment: It is really strange, I get downvotes on a regular basis without any reason, often directly after posting my answer.

Comment: I would say that it is not necessary to assume the existence of enough projectives, but certainly one should have $\otimes$ at least.

Comment: How do you define (and construct) Tor when there are not enough projectives? I mean without leaving the abelian category.

Comment: The same way as for any other derived functor: define it by representability of some other functor. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4371278/5191).

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. But this is what I meant with "construct". I wanted to have a criterion which enables us to construct Tor, not just characterize it.